# Trying to implement Facebook instant article page but I can't get the image view height to animate

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm trying to implement the following in my app:

1. A scrollview with an image view and a view as subviews.
2. As I drag down from the top of the scroll view, the image view  increases in height, in the aspect fill mode, giving the impression of zooming.
3. When I let go, the image returns to its original height.

So basically, I'm trying to replicate the Facebook app's instant article page.

The problem is that I can't animate the image view returning to its original size. It seems to always jerk back to it. UIView.animateWithDuration() doesn't work here for some reason:/

here is my code:
(imageHeight is an IBOutlet of the UIImageView's height constraint)

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let y = self.scrollView.contentOffset.y

    if y < 0 && self.imageHeight.constant < 500
    {
        self.imageHeight.constant += (-1*y)*0.5;
    }

}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    self.stoppedScrolling()

}


func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {


    if !decelerate
    {
        self.stoppedScrolling()
    }

}

func stoppedScrolling()
{

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1) { 

        self.imageHeight.constant = 180

    }

}
```

[Here's a gif of the result](http://i.giphy.com/g4D1etFNAa0H6.gif)
Also, it doesn't show in the gif but there's a half-second delay between end touches and resizing

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it cause by UIImageView's height constraint, I try to create the UI by code and use frame property to control it, it works.

Sorry about that I don't know how to write swift code, but I think that I can know what you mean, you must can read my code as well, like this:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@property UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property UIImageView *imageView;
@property bool needReceiveDraggingFlag;

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

_scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
_scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
_scrollView.delegate = self;
_scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width,_scrollView.frame.size.height*1.2f);
[self.view addSubview:_scrollView];

UILabel *lbInfo = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 300, 200, 30)];
lbInfo.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
lbInfo.text = @"Test label";
[_scrollView addSubview:lbInfo];

_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
_imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:_imageView];

_needReceiveDraggingFlag = YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
NSLog(@"scrollViewDidScroll");
if(_needReceiveDraggingFlag){
    float y = _scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    if (y<0 && _imageView.frame.size.width<300) {
        float nowImageLength = _imageView.frame.size.width;
        float targetImageLength = nowImageLength + -y*0.5f;
        _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, targetImageLength, targetImageLength);
    }
}
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{
NSLog(@"scrollViewDidEndDragging");
[self stoppedScrolling];
}

-(void)stoppedScrolling{
_needReceiveDraggingFlag = NO;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
} completion:^(BOOL isFinished){
    _needReceiveDraggingFlag = YES;
}];
}

@end
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It does seem to animate the changing height. However, the top of the image view doesn't remain clipped to the top margin. Any way to do that?

Comment: I think I got it. Just added self.imageView.center.y += y in scrollViewDidZoom() and achieved the required effect! Can you edit your answer ??

Comment: I just gave you some hints, and if you have got what you want, there is no reason to edit my answer, glad to help you.